# D3 adding force to single node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have made a grouped bubble chart using D3's force layout to create a force towards the middle, like so:

```
  var forceStrength = 0.03;
  var center = { x: widthBubbles / 2, y: heightBubbles / 2 };

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
     .velocityDecay(0.2)
     .force('x', d3.forceX().strength(forceStrength).x(center.x))
     .force('y', d3.forceY().strength(forceStrength).y(center.y))
     .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(charge))
     .on('tick', ticked);

  function charge(d) {
    return -forceStrength * Math.pow(d.r, 2.0);
  }

  function ticked() {
    bubbles
      .attr('cx', function (d) { return d.x; })
      .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y; });
  }
```

My chart looks something similar to this: [Gates Foundation Educational Spending](http://vallandingham.me/bubble_chart_v4/)

I want to be able to apply a force on a single node when it is clicked, so that the clicked nodes will move to another area. In the documentation of D3 there is something called "positioning forces", which according to the documentation is intended to be used for multiple nodes:

> While these forces can be used to position individual nodes, they are intended primarily for global forces that apply to all (or most) nodes.

So my question is if there is a way to apply forces to singles nodes in D3.

Comment: This might be just a special case of the solution discussed in [*"Collision Detection Lost After Toggle (d3v4)"*](/q/41479452).

Comment: It may be similar but my question was how to change the force on just one node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a function, which is called every time a bubbles is clicked:

```
  //Function for moving bubbles when selected
  function moveSelectedBubbles() {
    simulation.force('x', d3.forceX().strength(forceStrength).x(function(d){
      //Check if bubble is selected
      return (selectedCountries.indexOf(d.data.country) >= 0) ? selectedCenter.x : center.x;
    }));

  simulation.alpha(1).restart();

  }
```

But this function sets the force of every node each time a bubble is selected. Maybe there is a more efficient way to handle the case.

Comment: From your solution, it looks like your force is actually acting on all nodes, since you are setting it to `center.x` if it isn't selected. If this were not the case and you wanted to isolate just the one node/group of nodes, there is a cool mbostock recent block: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b1f0ee970299756bc12d60aedf53c13b that I found useful. Also, I think you should be able to move your `.x(function(d)...` code inside of the `forceX(here)` function to simplify things (I don't _think_ you should have to set this force every click handler btw).

Comment: One more thing: You could also store a temporary flag on the `d` object itself, e.g. `d.isSelected` and filter against that instead of recalculating the `indexOf` every time. (This would require you also to handle when to set this flag as false, obviously.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will check that out.